# How to optimize insert of multiple rows in a table in MySql?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a loop doing sequential insert millions of rows in a single MySQL table.

I wonder if it is possible to parallelize the insert or use a feature that increases the performance of insertion.

Code:

```
public static java.sql.Connection getConexaoMySQL() {        
    //atributo do tipo Connection 
    try { 
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
        Class.forName(driverName);  
        String serverName = "localhost";  
        String mydatabase ="tweets"; 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase; String username = "root";  
        String password = "admin";  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); 
        if (connection != null) { 
            status = ("Banco de Dados--->Conectado com sucesso!"); 
        } 
        else { 
            status = ("Banco de Dados--->Não foi possivel realizar conexão"); 
        } 
        return connection; 
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    { 
        System.out.println("O driver expecificado nao foi encontrado."); 
        return null; 
    } catch (SQLException e) {  
        System.out.println("Nao foi possivel conectar ao Banco de Dados."); 
        return null; 
    } 
} 

public static void insert(List<TweetsDB> list){
    for (TweetsDB x : list) { 

        preparedStmt.setString (1, x.getCandidate);
        preparedStmt.setString (2, x.getIDTweet);
        preparedStmt.setString (3, x.getIDUser);
        preparedStmt.setString (4, x.getUserScreenName);
        preparedStmt.setString (5, x.getUserName);
        preparedStmt.setString (6, x.getRetweets);
        preparedStmt.setTimestamp(7, x.getDate);
        preparedStmt.setString (8, x.getText);
        preparedStmt.setString (9, x.getHashtags);

        // execute the preparedstatement
        preparedStmt.execute();
    }   
}
```

Comment: yes, insert 1000 rows at a time. Ok, 200. Certainly a dupe question, maybe not well detailed! But not a terrible one.

Comment: Have you tried using batch statements?

Comment: No, I am layman in mysql.

Comment: That's associated with Java and JDBC, not with MySQL. Please show how you're inserting the data in your table, this is, show relevant code to help you.

Comment: what is associated with what @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @Drew batch statement is associated with Java and JDBC, not to MySQL. Also, I guess you can perform batch operations on other programming languages, but for the context of this question, this is related to Java, exactly at `Statement#addBatch`, `Statement#executeBatch` and related methods.

Comment: I am looking at the fastest way of bringing it in for the OP, which may be non java or any language, just mysql. 50% of the time, that is all you need. Beats any slow poke driver. Put a million rows on an AWS server, I can prove it. Moving on, you guys have a go at it

Comment: batch should help you.. please check this post http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm

Comment: Fastest would be to generate a CSV from your java code and use LOAD DATA INFILE  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html